# Send data in NodeJS to a ShoutCAST server

Tags: node.js, protocols, shoutcast

I want to send mp3 data to a ShoutCAST server using NodeJS but I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

I'm beginner in NodeJS. I've read [ShoutCAST protocol](http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_2_(Ultravox_2.1)_Protocol_Details) and somewhat understood it but because of my lack of knowledge in Node programming can't exactly do what I want.

Could someone tell me if it's possible to, and if it is then how to do it?

Comment: does you guys want more details or something ?